# Button hints obstruct controls below them and make reviewing changes in Documentation harder

Tags: bug, documentation, user-interface, user-experience

Buttons in Documentation have hints which act as links. This results in obstructing buttons below hints. For example, if I click where the red arrow points, the highlighted button above will be clicked, not the button right below the mouse cursor.

[image]

This happens every single time I open several proposed changes in row (by clicking middle mouse button to open pages in background tabs).

Possible solutions:

- Make hints click-through.
- Stop making hints act as links.
- Move hints to the empty space on the left or right.

Comment: You can also click the (non-hintified) link to the left.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this; I've been annoyed by it, but only noticed today when exactly it happens. Too often opening the review above…

Comment: No freehand drawings? :(

Comment: @Siguza Bug fixed.